# Talkback not pronouncing the button name

Tags: android, button, accessibility

In my app, Talkback is not pronouncing the name of the button. Instead it's just pronouncing as  **"button"**.
Can anyone help me to do the task?

I tried the following xml

```
 <Button 
            android:id="@+id/loginsuccess"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/submit_button"            
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             />
```

that's not working

Comment: @ModularSynth I have updated the code(xml) which i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply added a property android:contentDescription=" "  in the xml file, Like the following

```
<Button
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="0sp" 
            android:id="@+id/loginsuccess"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/submit_button"    
            android:contentDescription="login"      
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             />
```

that solved the problem.

Comment: that's what @user1506104 suggested what is the difference in that solution and yours.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following in button xml declaration:

```
android:contentDescription="buttonName"
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference it was because you didn't have `android:text` so there was nothing to read out.

Answer (score 0):

You must Content description is set on `Button`. Like this `android:contentDescription="login"`